# Use custom error classes with constrained types in Pydantic

Tags: pydantic

The [documentation](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#custom-errors) specifies that: *you can also define your own error classes, which can specify a custom error code, message template, and context*.

In the example from the link above, a validator is defined to validate an attribute and the custom error `NotABarError` is raised from the validation method, which then raises a Pydantic `ValidationError`.

Similarly, is there a way to raise custom exceptions with constrained types? The message could be the same as the default one from `pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError`, but raised from a custom error class, rather than the Pydantic's `ValidationError`?